# Using Angular2 Router in ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2, router, deeplink

Many developers need to use a more sophisticated router then the DeepLinker or the ionic native one is.

In many posts like this https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-updating-the-url-when-pushing-page-on-the-nav-stack/67683/8 I and other discussed how we can include angular2 router in ionic2. It looks like some people was able to do this and I think it would be great if someone can help us to implement the nativ router in ionic2.

We are creating a trasversal ionic2 app for mobile, pwa and webapp and we believe we can do it. But we as others need for this a working router like the @angular/router

Can someone help us? Some code examples or something else?

Comment: Have you found a way to implement routing into Ionic 2? Thanks